# Find out how much data is sent and received via a terminal command

Tags: linux

I'm working on a project where my client is billed exorbitant rates for data transfer on a boat. When they are in port, they use 3g and when they are out at sea they use sattelite.

Every 30 minutes I need to check to see what network I am attached to (moving vessel) but I need to give them specific information on how much data is actually used to make these calls.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any way to get the exact bytes that were sent out and received via terminal response.

Right now I am running this command to get the IP address that my ISP has assigned me.

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

Answer (score 2):

To identify which network is used right now you may check route table

```
netstat -r | grep default
```

You will see default interface used for connection.
There are multiple commands that will show you statistics for interface. E.g.

```
ip -s link show dev eth0
```

where eth0 interface identified from command above.

or

```
ethtool -S eth0
```

If you want to get data independently from interface(all data stats from boot) you may use IpExt sectoin of

```
netstat -s
```

All those metrics will provide system wide counters. For inspecting specific app you may use [iptables stats](https://www.linux.com/tutorials/bandwidth-monitoring-iptables/). There are owner module in iptables-extensions that may help. Here are example commands:

```
# sudo su
# iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner 1000 -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
# iptables -A INPUT -m connmark --mark 1 
# iptables -A OUTPUT -m connmark --mark 1
# iptables -nvL | grep -e Chain -e "connmark match  0x1"
```

Iptables will allow you to clear counters whenever it needed. Also owner module allow you [match packets associated with user group, process id and socket](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html).